# How to set the title of a Kendo Window in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have just been playing with the [Kendo Window Widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/window/overview)

From the documentation, it has the property "title", and is set using jquery as follows...

```
$("#window").kendoWindow({
actions: ["Custom", "Pin", "Refresh", "Maximize", "Minimize", "Close"],
draggable: false,
height: "300px",
modal: true,
pinned: false,
position: {
    top: 100,
    left: 100
},
resizable: false,
title: "Modal Window",
width: "500px"
});
```

I want to set this in angular, so I prepend the k-..

```
 <kendo-window k-width=100 
     k-height=300 k-visible=true k-title="title">            
 </kendo-window>
```

Once I do this, the window no longer appears, as can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/s0n4tu08/1/), where I have applied the title to the blue window. (remove the k-title) and it then works.

Any one know how to set the title, and how to discover what the name should be for Angular integration (I assume prepend with the "k-")

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for the kendo-title attrubute needs to be a `string`. So if you want to pass a static text as your title, you need to add single quotes:

```
<kendo-window k-width=100 
 k-height=300 k-visible=true k-title="'title'">
```

but if you want to bound the title to a model on the `$scope`, you should do this:

```
<kendo-window k-width=100 
 k-height=300 k-visible=true k-title="'{{title}}'">
```

Comment: Thankyou very much pesos_unior, that was the problem!